# "The woman ran across the street, and jumped into a luxury sedan that had just pulled up." Is this sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Is this sentence correct or do I need to rephrase it to convey it's meaning properly?

Alternative 1: The woman ran across the street, and jumped into a luxury sedan that had just pulled up (there).

Alternative 2: The woman ran across the street, and jumped into a luxury sedan that had just pulled up (across the street).

This doesn't sound right to me for the 2nd alternative. "Across the street" is redundant here.

Comment: What do you think? Would you understand what someone meant if they used the sentence that you are querying? If not, what would puzzle you?

Comment: Obviously she wouldn't have run across the street if the car had been on the same side !

Comment: What is your problem? Are you worried about ending the sentence with "up"? "Pulled up" is intransitive and does not need anything after it.

Answer (score 1):

Expressions like "there" and "across the street" are grammatically optional. If the meaning is clear you don't need them

Is it clear that the sedan was "across the street"? Yes, because that where the woman ran to.  So the meaning is clear without them.

Answer (score 1):

You do not **need** to add “there.” The woman was not going to jump into a car that was in a different city or that was on the side of the street which she had left. But you **may** add “there” if you prefer the way that sentence sounds. (I do prefer “there” being added, but I cannot explain why.)

You do not need to **repeat** “across the street.” And in this case, the unnecessary repetition strikes me as just being verbose and clumsy. But it is your sentence, and you **may** repeat it if that is to your taste.